# Read and dump [bracket, list] from and to yaml with python

Tags: python, yaml

I am trying to read and dump a list to yaml using the following code

```
with open(system_bsc_path) as f:
    system_bsc_dict = yaml.load(f)
with open(system_bsc_path, "w") as f:
    yaml.safe_dump(system_bsc_dict, f)
```

---

The input list, as in the file:

```
chs_per_cath: [[[10, 11, 12, 13], [13000, 13100, 13200, 13300]],
 [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [13400, 13500, 13600, 13700, 13800, 13900, 14000, 14100, 14200, 14300]],
 [[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], [13400, 13500, 13600, 13700, 13800, 13900, 14000, 14100, 14200, 14300]]]
```

is read properly into python

---

The output that gets dumped:

```
chs_per_cath:
- - - 10
    - 11
    - 12
    - 13
  - - 13000
    - 13100
    - 13200
    - 13300
- - - 16
    - 17
    - 18
    - 19
    - 20
    - 21
    - 22
    - 23
    - 24
    - 25
  - - 13400
    - 13500
    - 13600
    - 13700
    - 13800
    - 13900
    - 14000
    - 14100
    - 14200
    - 14300
- - - 32
    - 33
    - 34
    - 35
    - 36
    - 37
    - 38
    - 39
    - 40
    - 41
  - - 13400
    - 13500
    - 13600
    - 13700
    - 13800
    - 13900
    - 14000
    - 14100
    - 14200
    - 14300
```

---

How can I get the same output as the input?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you want to load, then dump (maybe after modifying some values), PyYAML is not the right tool, as it will mangle many things in the syntactic representation.

It will drop flow style as you noticed, but also drop comments, anchor/alias names, specific integer formats (octal, hex, binary), etc.

There is little control over the flow- vs block-style of the output in PyYAML. You can have all-block; node collections as flow,
and you can have all-flow, using the `default_flow_style` parameter to `safe_dump()`.

You'd be better of using `ruamel.yaml` (disclaimer: I am the author of that library), as it supports the now 10 year old YAML 1.2 standard (where PyYAML only handles the outdated YAML 1.1) and will get you output which is much closer, and often identical to your YAML input.

```
from ruamel.yaml import YAML

yaml = YAML()
with open(system_bsc_path) as f:
    system_bsc_dict = yaml.load(f)
with open(system_bsc_path, "w") as f:
    yaml.dump(system_bsc_dict, f)
```

If you are Python 3, you can use:

```
from pathlib import Path
yaml_file = Path(system_bsc_path)
system_bsc_dict = yaml.load(yaml_file)
yaml.dump(system_bsc_dict, yaml_file)
```

By default any *new* lists (and dicts) will be block style, if you want to add a flow-style list, then you can use `yaml.default_flow_style = True` to set all those lists, or using fine control by setting the flow attribute (`.fa`) on the special internal representation:

```
def FSlist(l):  # concert list into flow-style (default is block style)
    from ruamel.yaml.comments import CommentedSeq
    cs = CommentedSeq(l)
    cs.fa.set_flow_style()
    return cs

system_bsc_dict['existing_field'] = FSlist(["Boston Maestro 4000"])
```

Comment: Thanks! I am using 2.7. This works better than yaml, with one thing missing: when adding a field `system_bsc_dict['existing_field'] = ["Boston Maestro 4000"]` It outputs in `-dash style`, rather than in desired `[bracket style]` How can I set the style? Thanks

Comment: I updated my answer. For Python 2.7 you can install the `pathlib2` package, ruamel.yaml will work with that as well.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56542926/1126841), using `default_flow_style` should do the trick.

But seems that you actually need it set to `True`.

I.e.

```
>>> d = {'chs_per_cath': [[[10, 11, 12, 13], [13000, 13100, 13200, 13300]],
  [[16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25],
   [13400, 13500, 13600, 13700, 13800, 13900, 14000, 14100, 14200, 14300]],
  [[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41],
   [13400, 13500, 13600, 13700, 13800, 13900, 14000, 14100, 14200, 14300]]]}

>>> print(yaml.dump(d, default_flow_style=True))
{chs_per_cath: [[[10, 11, 12, 13], [13000, 13100, 13200, 13300]], [[16, 17, 18, 19,
        20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25], [13400, 13500, 13600, 13700, 13800, 13900, 14000,
        14100, 14200, 14300]], [[32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40, 41], [13400,
        13500, 13600, 13700, 13800, 13900, 14000, 14100, 14200, 14300]]]}
```

Comment: This indeed did the trick for the given list, but destroyed everything else in the document. For example, the original `system:
  testing: False` has become `{system: ...}`

Comment: Well, this means that you have inconsistent `yaml` formatting in source file. Both is valid yaml. Could you please explain what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

Please take a look at `default_flow_style` argument for  `yaml.dump()`.

> By default, PyYAML chooses the style of a collection depending on
>   whether it has nested collections. If a collection has nested
>   collections, it will be assigned the block style. Otherwise it will
>   have the flow style.
>
> If you want collections to be always serialized in the block style,
>   set the parameter default_flow_style of dump() to False.

https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation#DumpingYAML

Answer (score 0):

Details on `default_flow_style`

This should be a comment to the previous answers recommending the use of  `default_flow_style`, but my reputation is not high enough to comment...

The `default_flow_style` supports three different states:

- `True` - Everything in "Flow Style" using brackets
- `False` - Everything in "Block Style", one line per entry
- `None` - If a mapping or sequence consist only of scalars it will use "Flow Style", otherwise "Block Style"

The default value was changed on 2019/03/08 from `None` to `False` (see https://github.com/yaml/pyyaml/commit/507a464ce62c933bf667b2296a96ad45f0147873)

Because of the change the example from https://pyyaml.org/wiki/PyYAMLDocumentation does not match anymore.

```
>>> print(yaml.dump({'name': 'Silenthand Olleander', 'race': 'Human', 'traits': ['ONE_HAND', 'ONE_EYE']}))
name: Silenthand Olleander
race: Human
traits:
- ONE_HAND
- ONE_EYE
```

With `default_flow_style=None` it matches the documentation again:

```
    >>> print(yaml.dump({'name': 'Silenthand Olleander', 'race': 'Human', 'traits': ['ONE_HAND', 'ONE_EYE']}, 
... default_flow_style=None))
    name: Silenthand Olleander
    race: Human
    traits: [ONE_HAND, ONE_EYE]
```