# How to add internal whitespace to YAML sequence with Python ruamel

Tags: python, yaml, ruamel.yaml

I'm using ruamel.yaml to format YAML documents in Python:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import sys

from ruamel.yaml import *

yaml = YAML()

numbers = CommentedSeq()
numbers.fa.set_flow_style()
numbers.extend([1, 2, 3])

root = CommentedMap()
root['numbers'] = numbers
yaml.dump(root, sys.stdout)
```

I followed the advice in [this accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56543954/291033) to format the sequence inline. This outputs the following:

```
numbers: [1, 2, 3]
```

How can I add internal whitespace, and output this instead:

```
numbers: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `ruamel.yaml>=0.17.33` you can set the indicators on the `Emitter` class variable to influence this:

```py
import sys

from ruamel.yaml import YAML, CommentedSeq

yaml = YAML()
yaml.Emitter.flow_seq_start = '[ '      # defaults to '['
yaml.Emitter.flow_seq_end = ' ]'        # defaults to ']'
yaml.Emitter.flow_seq_separator = ' ,'  # defaults to ','

numbers = CommentedSeq()
numbers.fa.set_flow_style()
numbers.extend([1, 2, 3])

root = dict(numbers=numbers)

yaml.dump(root, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```
numbers: [ 1 , 2 , 3 ]
```

In `ruamel.yaml<=0.17.32` the bracket open and bracket closed were hardcoded in methods in the emitter, so the only thing you can do is
provide alternative methods for those

```py
import sys

from ruamel.yaml import *

class MyEmitter(ruamel.yaml.emitter.RoundTripEmitter):
    flow_start = '[ '   # these class attributes don't exist in RoundTripEmitter
    flow_end = ' ]'

    def expect_flow_sequence(self, force_flow_indent = False) -> None:
        if force_flow_indent:
            self.increase_indent(flow=True, sequence=True)
        ind = self.indents.seq_flow_align(
            self.best_sequence_indent, self.column, force_flow_indent
        )
        self.write_indicator(' ' * ind + self.flow_start, True, whitespace=True)
        if not force_flow_indent:
            self.increase_indent(flow=True, sequence=True)
        self.flow_context.append('[')
        self.state = self.expect_first_flow_sequence_item

    def expect_first_flow_sequence_item(self) -> None:
        if isinstance(self.event, SequenceEndEvent):
            self.indent = self.indents.pop()
            popped = self.flow_context.pop()
            assert popped == '['
            self.write_indicator(self.flow_end, False)
            if self.event.comment and self.event.comment[0]:
                # eol comment on empty flow sequence
                self.write_post_comment(self.event)
            elif self.flow_level == 0:
                self.write_line_break()
            self.state = self.states.pop()
        else:
            if self.canonical or self.column > self.best_width:
                self.write_indent()
            self.states.append(self.expect_flow_sequence_item)
            self.expect_node(sequence=True)

    def expect_flow_sequence_item(self) -> None:
        if isinstance(self.event, SequenceEndEvent):
            self.indent = self.indents.pop()
            popped = self.flow_context.pop()
            assert popped == '['
            if self.canonical:
                self.write_indicator(',', False)
                self.write_indent()
            self.write_indicator(self.flow_end, False)
            if self.event.comment and self.event.comment[0]:
                # eol comment on flow sequence
                self.write_post_comment(self.event)
            else:
                self.no_newline = False
            self.state = self.states.pop()
        else:
            self.write_indicator(',', False)
            if self.canonical or self.column > self.best_width:
                self.write_indent()
            self.states.append(self.expect_flow_sequence_item)
            self.expect_node(sequence=True)


yaml = YAML()
yaml.Emitter = MyEmitter

numbers = CommentedSeq()
numbers.fa.set_flow_style()
numbers.extend([1, 2, 3])

root = dict(numbers=numbers)

yaml.dump(root, sys.stdout)
```

which gives:

```yaml
numbers: [ 1, 2, 3 ]
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks. Will look at integrating that with my project.

Comment: Is there any way this could become part of the library, perhaps as an additional field on the flow attributes object?

Comment: I already "moved" the strings to attributes as in `MyEmitter` so that will be in the next version. Then you only have to update the class attributes on the default class that `YAML()` initialises, (`yaml.Emitter.flow_start = '[ '` and `yaml.Emitter.flow_end = ' ]'`) before dumping, instead of subclassing and overriding the three methods.

Comment: Hi Anthon, is there any chance you could release a new version with these changes? I would like to clean up my script, which currently uses your suggested patch. Thanks!

Comment: @HuwWalters in 0.17.33 this has been added, I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks again, that's really helpful.